# PDF and CDF of $R=\frac {X}{X+Y}$

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two exponentially distributed random variables with $\lambda$ and $\mu$ parameters respectively. Find the CDF and PDF of $R=\frac {X}{X+Y}$

I'm able to find the PDF of $S=X+Y$. But I'm unsure about the bounds of the integral when I want to calculate the PDF of $R$.

Answer (score 1):

For $0<r<1$ we have $P(R \leq r)=\int_0^{\infty}\int_{(1-r)x/r}^{\infty} \lambda e^{-\lambda x} \mu e^{-\mu y} dydx$ since $R \leq r$ iff $X \leq r(X+Y)$ iff $Y\geq (1-r)x/r$. The value is $\frac {\lambda r} {\lambda r+\mu (1-r)}$. PDF is its derivtive, namely, $\frac {\lambda \mu} {(\lambda r+\mu (1-r))^{2}}$.

Answer (score 1):

For $r$ in $R$'s support $[0,\,1]$,$$P(R\le r)=P(\tfrac{X}{Y}\le\tfrac{r}{1-r})=\int_{0}^{\infty}(1-e^{-\lambda yr/(1-r)})\mu e^{-\mu y}dy=\tfrac{\lambda r}{\lambda r+\mu\left(1-r\right)},$$so the PDF is $\tfrac{\lambda\mu}{\left(\lambda r+\mu\left(1-r\right)\right)^{2}}$. In the special case $\lambda=\mu$, $R\sim U(0,\,1)$.

Comment: Could you please explain a little about how you formed the integral?  Thank you. Because I calculated the integral of the above answer and got something different

Comment: @Sara If $Y=y$, $P(X\le ry/(1-r))=1-e^{-ry/(1-r)}$. We just want to average this function of $y$ over $Y$'s disribution.

Comment: So how is your answer different from the above answer? Sorry I'm not really good at this subject:)

Comment: @Sara The other answer writes the condition $R\le r$ in a different form, as $Y\ge(2-r)X/r$, but the two double integrals have the same value by Fubini's theorem.

Comment: Thank you very much